# SQL Query to find lecturer with highest amount of remaining leaves

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out query which show the lecturer with the highest number of remaining leaves. Here are the table name and fields:

```
Lecturer (lect_id, name, join_date, quit_date, no_of_leaves)
Leave (leave_id, lect_id, used_leave, start_date, end_date)
```

---

TABLE "Lecturer"

```
lect_id  name      join_date    quit_date   no_of_leaves
1        Andy      01/12/07     NULL        20
2        Bob       15/02/14     31/04/16    20
3        Carrot    05/07/15     NULL        15
```

TABLE "Leave"

```
leave_id    lect_id used_leave  start_date  end_date
101         1       3           04/01/09    06/01/09
102         1       4           12/02/12    15/02/12
103         3       6           23/02/16    28/02/16
```

---

With a right query, the result should show the name, lecturer ID, and the number of remaining leaves:

```
name    lect_id   NoOfLeavesLeft
Andy    1         13 (Resulted from 20 - 3 - 4)
Bob     2         20 (Remains the same because no leave taken)
Carrot  3         9 (Resulted from 15 - 6)
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT lect_id, name, SUM(no_of_leaves) NoOfLeavesLeft
FROM (
    (SELECT name, lect_id, no_of_leaves FROM Lecturer lc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT Null as col1, lect_id, - le.used_leave FROM Leave le)
    ) lect
GROUP BY lect_id
ORDER BY NoOfLeavesLeft DESC
```

My Questions:

I'm able to get the correct result out of this query. 
Is there any other way to query this instead of using UNION ALL and passing NULL as column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can`left join` and use aggregation:

```
select 
    l.lect_id, 
    l.name, 
    l.no_of_leaves - coalsece(sum(v.used_leave), 0) no_of_leaves_left
from lecturer l
left join leave v on v.lect_id = l.lect_id
group by l.lect_id, l.name
```

Another option, that avoids using aggregation and might perform better than the above query (especially with an index on `leave(lect_id, used_leave)`) , is to use an inline subquery, like so:

```
select 
    l.lect_id, 
    l.name, 
    l.no_of_leaves 
        - (
            select coalesce(sum(v.used_leave), 0)
            from leave v
            where v.lect_id = l.lect_id
        ) 
    no_of_leaves_left
from lecturer l
```

Comment: Your 1st solution works fine. But your 2nd solution gives me null if you don't use the COALESCE function

Comment: @leomord: I fixed the second query. I am curious to know which of the 3 solutions (the accepted answer and my two solutions) gives the best results in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1):

Join to a subquery which computes the total leaves taken by each lecturer, and then do the arithmetic:

```
SELECT
    l1.name,
    l1.lect_id,
    l1.no_of_leaves - COALESCE(l2.total_leave, 0) AS NoOfLeavesLeft
FROM Lecturer l1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT lect_id, SUM(used_leave) AS total_leave
    FROM `Leave`
    GROUP BY lect_id
) l2
    ON l1.lect_id = l2.lect_id;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Note: `LEAVE` is a reserved MySQL keyword, and you should avoid naming your tables and columns using it.